# How do I correctly Implement an event on successful form Submission using Google Tag Manager and Sitecore's Web Forms for Marketers?

Tags: forms, validation, sitecore, google-tag-manager, web-forms-for-marketers

I am attempting to track successful form Submissions using an event in Google Analytics via Google Tag Manager. My current setup successfully tracks when users submit the form. However, the event still fires even when the form submission is invalid and does not submit (ie a user hasn't filled out all of the required fields, clicks the submit button, the form attempts to validate, but comes back to the user with errors instead of submitting). I have the Check Validation feature on my listener checked which theoretically should keep the tag from firing if the form submission is prevented, so it's not the obvious error.

The form in question is created with Sitecore's Web Forms for Marketers. Colleagues of mine have had similar unsolved issues with their WFFM forms.

This particular form is used to gate content so that only users who fill out the form will have access to the content resource. So for example if I go to www.mydomain.com/resource I will be redirected to www.mydomain.com/form where if I fill out all of my information correctly and submit it I will then be redirected to the resource that I was originally attempting to view at www.mydomain.com/resource.

Here's my setup:

**Tag 1**

- Name: Form Submission Listener
- Type: Form Submit Listener
- Wait For Tags: Checked
- Max Wait Time: 2000 milliseconds
- Check Validation: Checked
- No advanced Settings
- Firing Rule: On form pages by URL

**Tag 2**

- Name: Event Form Submission
- Type: Universal Analytics
- Tracking ID: UA-.....
- Enable Display Advertising Features: Checked
- Track Type: Event
- Category: Form
- Action: Submission
- Label: {{Form resource URL}}
- Non-Interaction Hit: False
- No More Settings
- No Advanced Settings
- Firing Rules: {{event}} equals gtm.formSubmit

Theoretically the Check Validation check box should prevent the tag from firing if the form does not successfully submit, but in the case of this form it does not. The tag fires regardless of whether the form submits or not.

Apologies that I cannot link to the form as it is for a client and behind security.

Comment: The Check Validation feature doesn't actually handle form errors. That will still need to be done through your code or site plugins. Here is a resource from Google product forums: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/tag-manager/cvvPLUhhLKA. You might also want to check on Google's page for a more technical explanation: https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/3415369?hl=en#CheckValidation

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not sure that this answers my question though. The way I understand Check Validation is that it prevents the listener tag from firing (and thereby the event tag based on my rule) if the default action of the form (the submission) is prevented by other code on the page. We handle the form validation through code and prevent the form from being submitted when the required fields are not filled out and I can confirm that the invalid form submission never makes it into the form database.

Comment: The Check Validation feature is misleading in name. It doesn't actually look at any specific form validation. It actually looks at the state of the forms ability to perform the "default action." If your form validation code does not set preventDefault() on the form and the form fails validation checks, then the Check Validation feature has no effect. If you can not control your form validation code to set preventDefault(), you will have to use some other method to track valid form submission.

Comment: Thanks @kevintechie for the clarification. You're right, I wasn't quite understanding how this worked.

In this case though I had my dev add preventDefault(), but it didn't solve the problem. WFFM is already doing this from what he told me, but we tried adding it manually anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We were able to find an answer to our question via the Sitecore forums, but I wanted to pass it along for your benefit.

---

From Sitecore:

The Web Forms module provides the double level validation, 1-client validation, 2-server validation.

By default, the client validation is disable for the Required Field validator. So, when you press Submit, the form posts to the server, and returns with the validation error. It's a possible reason why Google Analytics considers that as a form submit.

- Find the following item in the Master database:
  /sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/System/System Validation/NotEmpty
- Find the "Enable Client Script" checkbox and enable it.
- Save and publish the item.
- Check whether the issue was fixed.

---

This fixed the issue for all of our text based fields. It did not fix the issue for the one checkbox on the form. I've followed up with sitecore on this, but I figured that I'd update here in the meantime.

With only the checkbox remaining I was also able to use a a macro and add to my original firing rule in google tag manager so that the event would not fire if the checkbox was not checked.

I created a Custom Javascript Macro called Radio Button Checked (not sure it's the best, but it worked), and added a new condition to my original Form Submission Rule: {{Radio Button Checked}} equals true

The macro:

```
function() {
    var radioName = "radioButtonName";
    try {
        var buttons = document.getElementsByName(radioName);
        for (var i = 0;i < buttons.length;i++){
            if(buttons[i].checked) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    } catch(e) {}
return false;
}
```

---

EDIT: Sitecore got back to me about the checkbox issue.

From Sitecore:

Currently the CheckBox field type doesn't have the client-side validation. I registered it as a bug for the WFFM module. I'll let you know as soon as it's fixed.

They let me know also that this isn't something that will be fixed near-term so I need to continue using my GTM workaround for the check box field.

Comment: Nice sleuthing and nice work-around. It will be easy to remove your custom JS macro after you deploy Sitecore's fix.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Chrome plugin "Tag Assistant" is super helpful in debugging these sorts of issues. It will show you what (if any) structural or implementation issues exist on a given page that might be preventing your intended tracking behavior (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk?hl=en)

My gut feel is that this issue is not specifically related to WFFM, but may be due to the implementation of the Tag Manager code on the page.  I seem to recall having an issue like this when the Tag Manager include code gets dumped inside the auto-generated .NET  tag when using WebForms in general.  Google's docs (https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/quickstart) say to put it immediately after the opening  tag, and I recall that being my issue with tracking form submits.

This is all from memory, so I could be wrong, but it's something else to check.

Good luck!

Comment: Tag Assistant is great. I've also been using the GTM debugger and Omnibug. Between those 3 usually I can get at what's going on, but WFFM is a tricky customer sometimes.

Turned out that the issue was specific to WFFM because of it's double validation.

Thanks for the help! I'll be sure to keep those tips in mind for any other issues.